# when I use object name I get 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I'm new with django. I'm really confused with views filters.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    age= models.CharField(max_length=2)
    post= models.ManyToManyField(Article)
    def __str__(self):              
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post

    def __str__(self):
        return self.age

class Meta:
    ordering = ('title','user',)
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def posting(request):
    details = Author.age.get(pk=request.user.id)
    return render(request,'home.html' , {'detail':details})
```

Now I need to get the current logged in user (age or title or post). When I execute the code I get the above error. How can I filter the particular object of logged in user?

Kindly suggest me some docs for views filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access fields after returning a model instance via the manager (default manager is named `objects`), not directly:

```
author = Author.objects.get(user=request.user)
age = author.age
```

Talking about *some docs*, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Author has an FK to User, it should be `.get(user=request.user)`.

Comment: By view filter, you mean *writing queries* or *views*? The link in the answer pretty much covers everything, with a nice tutorial.